# Run testSuite using command line android studio and generate code coverage report

Tags: android-studio, gradle, command-line, code-coverage, test-suite

I have 4 test suits(bunch of tests in each) each for a specific kind of user. I am trying to get code coverage for one of them. When I run the test suit, code coverage report not generating.
[image: Test suite]

So I tried running tests from command line(as shown below), but this is running all tests in all test suits, hence failing the tests and not generating the code coverage report. Can anyone please help me on how I can generate code coverage report? I used -Dtest.single and --tests to specify the testsuite to get the coverage report for, but no luck :(

```
gradlew createDebugCoverageReport -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.USERNAME=<username> -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.PASSWORD=<password>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can do this using gcloud command. Add the following at the end of your command       `--test-targets="class com.example.package.testsuite"`